# Weblogic 12c cmd property not found in autorun.inf

Tags: java, weblogic

I'm trying to install Weblogic version 12.1.2 (because I have to) on Windows, but it won't install.

I downloaded 'oepe-12.1.2.1-kepler-installer-win32.exe', which was the version it made available and ran the exe. After a few seconds into the GUI installer I get this:

```
cmd property not found in autorun.inf
```

So I expanded the exe, navigated to the Disk1 folder and ran what was in the autostart file:

```
java.exe  -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar
```

When I do this I get:

```
    Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from C:\Users\xxxxxxx
    Log: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\install2015-07-06_06-01-24PM.log
    [ERROR]: Installer has encountered an internal Error. Contact Oracle support with details
    [EXCEPTION]:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Any ideas? Could it be that I need JDK/JRE 6? I'm running 7. thanks.

the log file says this:

```
    singlePageValidataionData handlers  :[oracle.as.install.engine.modules.input.config.pagedata.PageHandler@4b4c7b84, oracle.as.install.engine.modules.input.config.pagedata.PageHandler@a413dbb, oracle.as.install.engine.modules.input.config.pagedata.PageHandler@413bc53f, oracle.as.install.engine.modules.input.config.pagedata.PageHandler@3b12cc8e]
    singlePageValidataionData handlers  :[oracle.as.install.engine.modules.input.config.pagedata.PageHandler@664d98b4]
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no oraInstaller in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.loadNativeLib(OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:1503)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.<clinit>(OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:50)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.util.SysInfo.getAvailableMemory(SysInfo.java:159)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.element.AvailableMemoryElement.<init>(AvailableMemoryElement.java:39)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.standard.StandardElementLocator.loadElements(StandardElementLocator.java:64)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.boot.ProfilerInitializer.initializeProfile(ProfilerInitializer.java:82)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.Statistics.launchModule(Statistics.java:321)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.InstallEngine.launchModule(InstallEngine.java:530)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.InstallEngine.processAndLaunchModules(InstallEngine.java:484)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.InstallEngine.startOperation(InstallEngine.java:437)
        at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.main(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:688)
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.InstallEngine.launchModule(InstallEngine.java:530)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.InstallEngine.processAndLaunchModules(InstallEngine.java:484)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.InstallEngine.startOperation(InstallEngine.java:437)
        at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.main(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:688)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no oraInstaller in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.loadNativeLib(OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:1503)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.<clinit>(OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:50)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.util.SysInfo.getAvailableMemory(SysInfo.java:159)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.element.AvailableMemoryElement.<init>(AvailableMemoryElement.java:39)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.standard.StandardElementLocator.loadElements(StandardElementLocator.java:64)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.boot.ProfilerInitializer.initializeProfile(ProfilerInitializer.java:82)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.statistics.Statistics.launchModule(Statistics.java:321)
        ... 8 more
    [ERROR]: Installer has encountered an internal Error. Contact Oracle support with details
    [EXCEPTION]:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: First of all, just so we are totally clear here, `oepe-12.1.2.1-kepler-installer-win32.exe` is not a WebLogic installer. It is most likely an installer for Eclipse with [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html) bundled in (though it may just be an installer that adds OEPE to Eclipse). So, second, I'm curious where you got this installer. You say it is "the version it made available," but what is "it"?

Comment: Agree with @dcsohl - are you using the correct installer? Also - this question has nothing to do with programming and as such, is not meant for a site like SO

Comment: Yes, my fault, I should have downloaded the 'generic' version, which I didn't see. It's installed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my fault, I should have downloaded the 'generic' version, which I didn't see. It's installed now :)

No idea why it refuses to install though, so if anyone else tries the exe and comes here, I have no answer.